# How can I show tr with same class in same tbody

Tags: php, html

I have:

```
<tbody>
<tr class='default'></tr>
<tr class='sample'></tr>
<tr class='sample'></tr>
<tr class='sample'></tr>
<tr class='default'></tr>
</tbody>
```

All of the classes are coming from foreach loop in same sequence.
Now I want to display tr with default class in separate tbody and tr with sample class in different tbody like below

```
 <tbody>
    <tr class='default'></tr>
    <tr class='default'></tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody>
    <tr class='sample'></tr>
    <tr class='sample'></tr>
    <tr class='sample'></tr>
</tbody>
```

how can i do so?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: see all the classes default and sample coming from a single foreach loop soo i am not able to do so in my code.

Comment: please post your full code to get better idea about your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can define styles for the tbody's and have the tr's styled depending on their parent:

html:

```
<tbody class="default">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
 </tbody>

 <tbody class="sample">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

style:

```
tbody.default tr { ... }
tbody.sample tr { ... }
```